# Insert data from C# into SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have nearly 7 billion rows of data in memory (`list<T>` and `sortedlist<T,T>`) in C#. I want to insert this data into tables in SQL Server. To do this, I define different `SqlConnection` for each collection and set connection pool to False.

First, I tried to insert data with connected mode (`ExecuteNonQuery`). Even I defined `Parallel.Invoke` and called all insert methods for different collections concurrently, it is too slow and up to now I couldn't finish it (I couldn't discriminate any differences between sequential and concurrent insert).

Also, I tried to create an object from `SqlDataTable`. To fill tables I read all data from collections once and add data to `SqlDataTable`. In this case I set `SqlBatchSize=10000` and `SqlTimeOut=0` for `SqlBulkCopy`. But this one also is very slow.

How can I insert a huge amount of data into SQL Server fast?

Comment: are you using SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1):

Look for 'BULK INSERT'. The technique is available for various RDBMS. Basically, you create a (text)file with one line per record and tell the server to consume this text file. This is the fastest approach I could think of. I import 50 million rows in a couple of seconds that way.

Answer (score 1):

You already discovered `SqlBulkCopy` but you say it is slow. This can be because of two reasons:

1. You are using too small batches. Try to stream the rows in using a custom IDataReader that you pass to `WriteToServer` (or just use bigger DataTables)
2. Your table has nonclustered indexes. Disable them pre-import and regenerate them

You can't go faster than with bulk-import, though.